# insert text data values eg(date time PH value) in Mongodb every 3 hours automatically using java

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a `mongodb` database, I need to insert text data values eg(date time PH value) every 3 hours automatically using java.
Need help

I have made a `mongodb` database called project and collection called Water Monetering system

also here is the basic layout of java- mongodb integration

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoException;
import com.mongodb.WriteConcern;
import com.mongodb.DB;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class MongoDBJDBC{

  public static void main( String args[] ){

     try{
        // To connect to mongodb server
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017 );
        // Now connect to your databases
        DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "project" );
        System.out.println("Connect to database successfully");

        DBCollection coll = db.getCollection("WaterMoneteringSystem");
        System.out.println("Collection WaterMoneteringSystem selected successfully");
        BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("title", "Watermoneteringsystem").
        append("Date", "date").
        append("time", "time").
        append("value", "ph").
        coll.insert(doc);
        System.out.println("Document inserted successfully");

     }catch(Exception e){
       System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
   }
}
}
```

I am not getting how data(date time PH) in text box can be implemented

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Why not put the values you want to store in the call to each field's `append`? It's the second argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("title", "Watermoneteringsystem").
append("Date", "date").
append("time", "time").
append("value", "ph");
```

You need something like:

```
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("title", "Watermoneteringsystem").
append("Date", new Date()).
append("value", "ph");
```

The `new Date()` call will set today's date and time in there (you don't need separate fields for date and time).

But the `"ph"` bit needs to come from some other place - where are you getting the ph values from?  Is it going to be an argument (i.e. in args[])? Is it coming from a file, or external system?

Assuming it's something you can pass in to the method, you can do something like:

```
String phValue = args[0];
BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject("title", "Watermoneteringsystem").
append("Date", new Date()).
append("value", phValue);
```

I'd suggest renaming the field to something like "ph" or "phValue" as well, since "value" is not a helpful field name.

Take a look at the [MongoDB and Java](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/) documentation, there are more examples there in how to use MongoDB from Java.